# @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") vs. @GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to hibernate. I do not understand the the following two primary key generation strategies:

1. Identity
2. Sequence

Can someone please explain how these two work and what is the difference between these two?

Comment: https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Quoting [Java Persistence/Identity and Sequencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing):

> **Identity** sequencing uses **special IDENTITY columns** in the database to allow the database to automatically assign an id to the object when its row is inserted. Identity columns are supported in many databases, such as **MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and Postgres**. Oracle does not support IDENTITY columns but they can be simulated through using sequence objects and triggers.

In plain English: you mark at most one `ID` column in your table as IDENTITY. The database engine will put *next available* value for you automatically.

And:

> **Sequence** objects use **special database objects** to generate ids. Sequence objects are only supported in some databases, such as **Oracle, DB2, and Postgres**. Usually, a SEQUENCE object has a name, an INCREMENT, and other database object settings. Each time the `<sequence>.NEXTVAL` is selected the sequence is incremented by the INCREMENT.

Sequences are more flexible and slightly more complex. You define an extra object in your database next to tables, triggers, etc. called *sequences*. Sequences are basically named counter you can use anywhere inside queries.

Comment: [Oracle supports IDENTITY strategy since version 12c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1)

Comment: The following article explains the difference between those two types clearly https://www.sqlshack.com/difference-between-identity-sequence-in-sql-server/