# Invalid conversion requested, oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.StringToNUMBER

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c with hibernate-core 5.0.1.Final.

Table sturcture as follows

```
create table tracer (
 id number(10,0) generated as identity, 
 creation_time timestamp,
 request varchar2(4000 char),
 requestor varchar2(255 char),
 response varchar2(4000 char),
 resp varchar2(4000 char),
 type varchar2(255 char), 
 primary key (id)
)
```

Java Class has id property

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;
```

When I try to insert data using hibernate I will get exception

```
ERROR: Invalid conversion requested
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.company.Tracer ]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:49)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2730)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3300)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:474)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:163)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:198)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
at com.company.Test.main(Test.java:75)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.StringToNUMBER(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:832)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getNUMBER(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:239)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getInt(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:527)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getInt(GeneratedStatement.java:217)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:573)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.get(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:116)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:73)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:88)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)
at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.StringToNUMBER(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:825)
... 28 more
```

Not able to understand this issue. Provide some direction

Comment: Do you use (in Oracle) intentionally [IDENTITY and not SEQUENCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955074/generatedvaluestrategy-identity-vs-generatedvaluestrategy-sequence)?

Comment: Yes, I use identity intentionally because when i use sequence on table hibernate do'not uses trigger to insert id and i try to insert value from 2 different project. I faced unique constraint issue