# Generated value in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm new to postgres sql database. I'm developing a project in JAVA using postgres sql and hibernate. I cant' achieve the auto increment i.e Generated value like MySql and MSSQL server. How to implement that? Thanks in advance.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer id;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") vs. @GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955074/generatedvaluestrategy-identity-vs-generatedvaluestrategy-sequence)

Comment: Add your create table statement.

Comment: Are you defining the column as 'SERIAL' on the database creation script?

Comment: I'm using hibernate. So I don't have _create table statement_.

Comment: I used the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. But I didn't get the correct output.

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id