# Hibernate GenerationType.IDENTITY vs GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm looking for clarification on this question: [@GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") vs. @GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955074/generatedvaluestrategy-identity-vs-generatedvaluestrategy-sequence) (nearly a decade old has anything changed?)

Getting started with learning jpa, the following generation types both seem to auto-increment the primary keys that get generated by 1.

Identity:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Sequence:

```java
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "my_sequence",
    sequenceName = "my_sequence",
    allocationSize = 1
)
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "my_sequence"
)
private Long id;
```

I understand that the sequence object created by `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` is not tied directly to a table in the way `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is. The old question mentions that sequence can be more flexible. Are there any *objective* pros or cons to choosing one of these strategies over the other? Also anything new considering the age of the question being referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's stated in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity):

> It is important to realize that using `IDENTITY` columns imposes a runtime behavior where the entity row **must** be physically inserted prior to the identifier value being known.
>
> This can mess up extended persistence contexts (long conversations). Because of the runtime imposition/inconsistency, *Hibernate suggests other forms of identifier value generation be used (e.g. SEQUENCE).*
>
> *There is yet another important runtime impact of choosing IDENTITY generation: Hibernate will not be able to batch INSERT statements for the entities using the IDENTITY generation.*
>
> The importance of this depends on the application-specific use cases. If the application is not usually creating many new instances of a given entity type using the IDENTITY generator, then this limitation will be less important since batching would not have been very helpful anyway.